# Which type lockring removal tool do I need

Tags: cassette

I'm trying to learn DIY cassette removal as I want to swap one on a buckled wheel. I have another cassette which uses an FR5 but it doesn't fit this one.

When checking [this site](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/determining-cassette-freewheel-type) it looks like it's a HCW-17 tool but specifically mentions that's for single speed bikes which this is not.  It also says it should have 2-8 splines but mine (and the one in the picture on the site) has 9 splines.

This tool is a fair bit more expensive than the FR-5 tool so I just want to make sure it's the right one before I go ahead.

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture where you're about 45 degrees to the left or right of where you are now? In other words, so that we can see some of the surface of the hub, we need to see if there are threads on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the smallest sprocket is the lockring on this cassette. I believe you need two chainwhips to remove it.

The smallest sprocket looks very badly worn. I'd replace this cassette rather than re-use.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a lock ring in this picture.  Agree with Argenti's that the small sprocket acts as lock ring.  This is how the earliest cassettes were held in place on a freehub. Shimano's "Uniglide" system is an example.

Comment: @jeff, I looked at the picture again and can't see what the smallest sprocket is threading into, so I'm inclined to think that there is no lockring. Maybe it was removed previously.

Comment: I, too, wondered about that. The old Uniglide freehubs have external threads at the end of the hub and the (typically) 14 tooth small sprocket came with the spacer on it, giving ample room for mating threads.  Also, that's a 6-sprocket cluster and I'm not seeing any ramping on the sprockets--additional evidence pointing to Uniglide.

Comment: Check out the [Uniglide](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/k7.html) section of this Sheldon Brown article.  My memory didn't serve me well in my last comment. The bit about the 14t sprocket and spacer is incorrect and Uniglide could have up to 8 speeds, whereas I thought only 5 or 6.

Comment: @jeff There is a narrow spline and wide gap at about 1 o'clock so I guess it's 'Uniglide compatible Hyperglide'

Comment: Thanks to you both. I'll do some research into Uniglide. Even if it's worn out I might still get a bit more use out of it, and either way taking it off will be good practice. :D